# AWS Datastore not saving users in the database on Android

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, react-native, aws-amplify

I have a code that will save user in the database on my profile screen, but the code worked fine on iOS, but on android it throws a "Possible unhandled Promise Rejection" with "TypeError: Symbol.asyncIterator is not defined."
Please how can solve the issue on Android so that it can save to database? I am working with React Native.
Here is the code snippet:

```js
import {Auth, DataStore} from 'aws-amplify';

const ProfileScreen = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [bio, setBio] = useState('');
    const [gender, setGender] = useState();
    const [lookingfor, setLookingfor] = useState();

    const isValid = () => {
        return name && bio && gender && lookingfor;
    };

    const save = () => {
        if(!isValid()) {
            console.warn('Not valid');
            return;
        }

        const newUser = new User({
            name,
            bio,
            gender,
            lookingfor,
            image: 'https://notjustdev-dummy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/avatars/elon.png',
        });

        DataStore.save(newUser);

    };
    return ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing the same project. It worked for me when I did:

```
npm install @azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill
```

Then added:

```
import '@azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill';
```

at the very top of my imports in the page I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js/), since save returns a promise instead of doing the opeartion itself, add await or subscribe with then to the save function;

```
await DataStore.save(newUser);
```

or

```
DataStore.save(newUser).then(...);
```

Comment: I have tried using await DataStore.save(newUser); but I still got the same TypeError: Symbol.asyncIterator is not defined.

Comment: It may be related with your node version. Can you try the second option with .then notation?

Comment: @BenjaminIkwuagwu did you find any answers to this?